# Invalid template file for custom module

Tags: magento2, template, magento2.3.3, template-override

I am Creating a simple layout block and template, but it is giving error

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Test_Module::stock_left.phtml' in module: 'Test_Module' block's name: 'productleft'

**layout** `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout = "1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Test\Module\Block\StockLeft" name="productleft" template="Test_Module::stock_left.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Block** `StockLeft.php`

```
<?php 

namespace Test\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\view\Element\Template;

class StockLeft extends Template{

}
```

**Template :** `stock_left.phtml`

```
<?php
/**@var \Test\Module\Block\stockleft $blocks */

?>

<h1>hello world</h1>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please let me know your template's file path ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya Template path is     vendorname/modulename/view/frontend/template/stock_left.phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your template file inside **`templates`** directory not **`template`** like

in **Module** :

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/template.phtml

or in **Theme** :

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/template.phtml

Create your template file here in your module

> app/code/Test/Module/view/frontend/templates/stock_left.phtml

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks @kishan savaliya it works

Comment: Can you please accept my answer ? @vinaysirige

Comment: thanks it worked

Comment: That will helpful to me :)

Comment: I accepted the Answer

Comment: Thanks Buddy. :)

Answer (score 0):

In `Block` you have a typo.

use this: `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`

Let me know if this helps

Thnx